mudblazor table server multipage with multiselect
I want to use the table component in server mode and use the multiselect.
Currently, when I select a box on page 1, when I go to page 2 my selection is not saved (if I go back to page 1 the box is no longer checked).
Do you have a solution to this problem?
Thank you very much in advance
The problem seems to come from the mudblazor component, since in the documentation, if I edit the "Server Side Filtering, Sorting and Pagination" exemple and add the
MultiSelection=“true” option
(https://mudblazor.com/components/table#server-side-filtering,-sorting-and-pagination)
I see the same problem as in my application.

Navigating from page A to page B disposes of all components on page A. When you go back to page A, everything is then reloaded. You would need to add your own state management to store data between navigation.

Hello Anu6is, when you say page A and page B, you say table page? because i'm conscient that if I change page in my webapp i lose my selected boxes, but in a one table, it is current to navigate and select different line in differente table pages. i need a custom implementation ?

Oh, you meant table pages? I assumed navigation across application pages. Sorry... see possible solution below

Since you're using server data, you are fetching new objects every time you paginate on the table. As such, you'd likely need to define a Comparer for your table so it knows that the previously selected object is the same as the newly fetched object.
<MudTable @ref="table" ServerData="ServerReload" Comparer="_comparer" 
Dense Hover MultiSelection>

public class ElementComparer : IEqualityComparer<Element>
{
    public bool Equals(Element? a, Element? b) => a?.Sign == b?.Sign;

    public int GetHashCode(Element x) => HashCode.Combine(x.Sign);
}

Executable Example
